# About Basic Auth

Tags: c#, http, request

I'm trying to get some data from one api, this is mi code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DriverSenstarNMS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient()) 
            {
                string url = "http://localhost/api/devices/";

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "user:pass");
                var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
                var res = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                dynamic r = JObject.Parse(res);

                Console.WriteLine(r);
            }
               
        }
    }
}
```

currently I'm having:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in System.Net.Http.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Net.Http.dll
The format of value 'senstar:senstar' is invalid
```

The need to add basic auth, what's wrong?

Initially added the url, then added the authorization through the header, sent the request and then got the response

Answer (score 0):

The format of the `Authorization` header for basic auth is

```
Authorization: Basic username:base64encode(password)
```

Comment: I added ```client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization: Basic user: base64encode(pass)");``` but I got this error ```No overload for method 'Add' takes 1 arguments Driver pass```